# Can I use condition in type alias in C++20?

Tags: c++, template-meta-programming, constexpr, c++20

As C++ expands to fuse normal computations and type computations I wonder if there is a way to have something like this work?

```
static const int x = 47;

using T = (x%2) ? int : double;
```

I know I can use the decltype on a template function that returns the different types based on if constepr, but I wanted something short like my original example.

```
template<auto i> auto determine_type(){
    if constexpr(i%2) {
        return int{};
    } else {
        return double{};
    }
}
```

note: I am happy to use C++20

Comment: What would be a use case for something like that? Or is it just curiosity?

Comment: `std::conditional`? it has been around for a while

Comment: @Rakete1111 mostly curiosity about language limitations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
using T = std::conditional_t<(i % 2), int, double>;
```

For more complex constructions, your approach has too many limitations on the type - would be better to do it this way:

```
template<auto i>
constexpr auto determine_type() {
    if constexpr (i%2) {
        return std::type_identity<int>{};
    } else {
        return std::type_identity<double>{};
    }
}

using T = /* no typename necessary */ decltype(determine_type<i>())::type;
```

Comment: And that's been around since C++11.

Comment: What are the limitations? Requirement for default ctor, move/copy ctor?

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl Default initializable, returnable, subject to decay.